# Iterating HashSet of size 10 takes 7-8 seconds

Tags: java, jpa, set, hashset

I have an JPA entity A which has a many to one relation with JPA entity B. In the A.java class I have a @OneToMany mapping to B and a private HashSet data member.
When I fetch all entities A from the DB, and for each entity A I iterate over all Bs it has a relation with. The code is below.

```
List<A> allAs = getAllAs()
for(A a : allAs)
{
  HashSet<B> allBs = a.getAllBs()
  LOG.(X1)
  for(B b : allBs)
  {
    LOG.(X2)
    // doing something
  }
}
```

For the first iteration for both the loops(when both are in their first iteration simultaneously ) the time diff between X1 and X2 is 7-8 seconds. The size of all Lists and Sets is less than 20. I have no idea what the CPU is doing between the Log X1 and X2. Anyone know if it takes some extra time for CPU to fetch iterator for HashSet(sounds ridiculous, I know). This is very puzzling for me, if anyone has any clues please let me know.

Comment: Before anything else, enable query log output on your database itself, check which queries are actually being executed, and what the query execution time is.

Comment: Are you opening a DB connection in this code?  If so consider using DBCP.

Comment: I am opening a DB connection but this is happening after that. These logs are from a synchronous code chunk, just iterating over a HashSet. Also the output is fine so yes the query is being executed properly.